# Closing Etiquette: Why Do Some Answer *and* Close?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, vote-to-close, answers

I've noticed quite a few cases where people not only vote to close a question, but then also answer said question. At best this is just silly, and at worst it is totally hypocritical and seems almost like rep mining (since often the closers answers are the only ones that remain to be voted on since no new answers can be given).

If you want to close a question, it makes more sense to simply add a comment if you feel the need to say something. This also leaves the option open for the author of the question to delete it if they want to. If the author realizes they've asked a duplicate, or they want to avoid the onslaught of downvotes that can often accompany a closed question, they should be allowed to delete it. However, if any answers to the question have upvotes, the author can't delete it.

So why do people answer *and* close? Should we try to crack down on this sort of thing, via either new features, clearly stating it in the FAQs, or just getting the word out through commenting when we see it?

Just to clarify, I'm asking this in relation to the main sites, not the per-site meta.

Comment: examples please.

Comment: Here's a recent one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109641/promoting-a-technical-blog-closed Users **Jonathan Sampson** and **Jeff Yates** voted to close and also answered.

Comment: @Jeff and Welbog: I added a recent link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107943/stackoverflow-source-code-closed Another one, this time from **Greg Hewgill**. In this case I would have posted a comment with the same text as his answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105258/popular-web-design-discussion-forums-on-the-web/1105283#1105283 Another example.  Didn't get closed but I voted for it and answered it.

Comment: This is exactly why reputation needs to be regularly recalculated (or at least a targetted rep recalc triggered for those who posted on closed questions), because one "cannot" get reputation for posting on a closed question. Yet, because the recalc is never done, these users get to keep their illegitimate rep pretty much forever.

Comment: Especially when it's  a flamestarter like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078736/fortran-vs-c-does-fortran-still-hold-any-advantage-in-numerical-analysis-thes . Answer and get upvotes of supporters of yours side of the flamewar and close to have no competitors.

Comment: I tend to answer then vote migrate. I often have no account on the migration target so if I don't answer right then (answers move when migrating) I miss the chance.

Comment: In cases where someone votes to close the question as "not constructive" or "off-topic" and also answers the question, it seems to be a plain and simple case of rep whoring.

Comment: I know this is late to the party.  I don't close and answer often, but will do so for well-written off-topic questions I feel have a good chance of getting migrated.  The rep would appear on the destination site, and if I can provide a good answer I see no reason not to.

Comment: I occasionally vote to close as a duplicate after answering. I typically find the duplicate after researching to improve my answer.

Comment: @Quantas94 can you explain your bounty? What kind of recent changes would've changed the relevance of the existing answers?

Comment: I can say I have done this a few times. Vote to close as the question is poorly formatted or less clear as to what is wanted but at the same time I think I have an idea on what they need so I will post a solution so they have something to work with and at the same time I try to let them know what they can do in the future to improve on their questions. Like posting in the comments that they may want to read [Minimal-Reproducible-Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Welbog it is not also not found. :) it is indeed a bit unique behavior.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

For questions about Stack Overflow itself that *should* have been asked on the meta site in the first place, I believe this an acceptable way to handle it. The question should be closed (and later deleted or migrated), but go ahead and give the asker the answer they were looking for first so we don't leave them with an absolutely horrible experience for it. It's part of keeping Stack Overflow a welcoming and inclusive environment.

You may also want to mark an answer to this type of question as community wiki (though I often forget). I take a similar approach for duplicates, as well.

Comment: Can't you easily give them an answer in the comments?

Comment: You could, but since it really is an answer that's kind of pointless.

Comment: "Why do some people answer in comments?" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments - Can't please everybody it seems :)

Comment: I can kinda see your point. With regard to making the answer wiki, does the author still have the chance to delete the question even if a wikied answer has upvotes?

Comment: @Jonathan: So true. =)

Comment: "so we don't leave them with an absolutely horrible experience for it."  This is exactly my thought behind answering and voting to close at the same time.  If I know a quick answer or website to point them to, why not?

Comment: -1 for "...and later deleted". Being active in [reopening closed questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/vote-to-reopen/info) I find this statement misleading and harmful

Comment: @gnat Notice the condition in my answer: this is only about questions that should have been asked on meta in the first place. If you're re-opening those, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I see, thanks for explaining

Comment: This still seems hypocritical.  If the question deserves an answer, then it deserves the best possible answer.  Answering and voting to close deprives other members of the community to provide a better answer.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Old now, but this just came back to my attention. The response to that argument is the best possible answer for a question like this would be had by moving it to the meta site. Since that's one of the close reasons, I still feel like this is the best option.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: If you want to  make it a full-blown answer, then ask and answer on the relevant meta site instead.

Answer (score 56):

If I know the answer (or can be helpful), I'll give it. If the question isn't supposed to be asked, I'll vote to close. I see it as generous, not hypocritical - after all, I didn't make the rules.

I don't see anything wrong with this. We're being strict, but generous. Additionally, I think it makes a good impression on those asking the question who may not be entirely sure what the scope of SO is. They'll learn about the scope, but also see that the people here are not psycho-thread-killers who want to dominate the platform - we're genuinely here to help.

Comment: Ok then, how about a new feature: You can't get any rep from answers in a question you voted to close. Closing prevents competition. If the question deserves to be closed, it doesn't need to generate rep.

Comment: @Kelly - There's no way to implement this unless you can see the future, since questions can get reopened. Also, you can vote to close, but it may not be closed, so answering and voting to close seem perfectly fine.

Comment: @Peter - Future state doesn't matter. Answers to questions to questions that you've voted to close shouldn't generate any rep for you, regardless whether the question has been closed/reopened/reclosed/etc.

Comment: One problem, is that your answer make stop the quesions being auto deleted.

Comment: @KellyS.French: High-rep users don't care about rep that much. Certainly not about not getting rep from some narrow niche of questions.

Answer (score 25):

I do it precisely for the reason that "It may not get closed so, I'm going to go ahead and answer it anyway just in case"

Comment: ..or in some cases it may get reopened.

Answer (score 14):

I'll most often do this when it seems iffy as to whether or not a question will actually be closed (very subjective questions, for instance). In those cases, I'll mark my answer Community Wiki, out of hope that, if I fail to close, perhaps I can at least encourage other authors to follow suit.

Occasionally, I'll do the same for questions where I can't fit my reply into a comment, either because of length or formatting restrictions. Again, I'll mark it as CW.

If I remember, I'll try to go back and delete the answer if and when the question *is* finally closed.

Yes, it's a bit dodgy, but it is my hope that marking the answer CW will mitigate this (not that it's prevented some folks from accusing me of inconsistency or gaming, but I suspect they'd have found something to whine about anyway).

Comment: I never realized that people use this CW with so much care.

Comment: But making every answer posting to a closed question a CW fair? I see some people answer, vote to close as dupe and answer the original too with non wiki answers and receive upvotes by answering exact dupes and originals both. What is the best thing to do in this case?

Answer (score 12):

Do we have any numbers on whether the people who ask close-worthy questions tend to do so repeatedly, or whether closed questions tend to come from different users all the time?

Most of the answers here remind me of the most popular example of reinforcement I heard in psych classes in college. It comes down to this: if your kid is throwing a tantrum, don't give in. If you do, it teaches You, Jr. that throwing a tantrum is an effective method of getting what he wants, and he'll do it again. And the longer you wait before you cave, the more your kid learns that persistence pays off, no matter how angry you get or how much you say you're serious. Twenty years later, [you're Christopher Walken](https://youtu.be/-cPrQ-GqpjU?t=2m13s).

The point is that if you answer questions that you vote to close, you're not really motivating people to ask better questions. You're just training them to expect some mean words with their answers. Of course, without evidence either way, that's just a theory.

Comment: @Erik found another source for that video. And now I have another thing on my "to do someday" list: see if maybe I can tease out any trends in closing stats.

Answer (score 11):

I've done it a few times.  Usually it's along the lines of "this isn't really programming related, but I happen to know your answer, so here it is."  Worst case, they don't get the answer and the don't come back, same as if I just voted to close.  But maybe, just maybe, they'll see it in time and get the answer they need *and* learn about how to use SO.

Answer (score 10):

I sometimes answer off-topic questions that belong on other SE sites and vote them off-topic. *If* they turn out to be migrated later, the answer will be migrated as well, and will compete with other answers on the proper community site. I don't usually care enough about off-topic questions to make the effort to watch if they get migrated so that I could answer once they are on the correct site.

Answer (score 8):

I have only answered a question that I voted to close once (that I can remember). It was a [Blankman question that he had asked 15 minutes prior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840413/), but I hadn't seen this until after he had accepted my answer.

This really irked me to the point that I e-mailed Jeff about it to ask his opinion on the matter. I really wish I could take that answer back but it was already accepted so I couldn't.

I'm mad at myself for not having checked if the question had been asked by the same user before I posted an answer. Especially a user I know asks the same questions over and over again. I would gladly take back that answer and lose all the rep I gained from it.

Comment: It's really not that big of a deal, since your answer can be merged with those on the duplicate. Who knows, your perspective may have even added something that may have been helpful to others. :)

Answer (score 5):

I've spotted this behaviour a few times.  And I always downvote the answer.

Comment: What about answers given by those who do not vote to close, but actually should know better...?

Comment: @Arjan: I think you've hit on an even bigger problem than the one we're discussing here: 3k+ users who *still* don't clearly understand the goals of the site.

Comment: This seems to go against what votes are for (to categorize answers as helpful or not)..... Also, what if the answerer is answering in case it gets reopened? Or they weren't sure that it will get closed? Or they just wanted to be helpful and save a click for people who get to that answer and then have to click again to reach the original.

Comment: @PeterAjtai, an answer that leads to more bad quesions being asked is not helpfull

Answer (score 4):

If I'm going to do this---and I do occasionally---I generally make my answer CW explicitly because of the reputation thing.

Why do I do it? Usually because I think the question

1. is good on its own merits
2. is likely to be closed
3. shows that the asker/querent is suffering from some misunderstanding that could cause him or her trouble
4. has no answer which would tend to dispel the misunderstanding.

In short, I'm trying to be helpful to a confused soul.

Answer (score 4):

I have also answered questions that I have voted to close.  Especially since I am now a [moderator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) I try to be mindful of the fact that this can block competing answers and I limit that behavior.

Nevertheless the concern over "reputation" may be unnecessary.  If the community likes the question it should be reopened, and if not it should be deleted.  (Or as Ianzz reminds in his answer the question may be migrated to a site where the answer is appreciated.)  If this is done within the window where reputation does not become permanent (90 days I believe) then no "ill gotten gain" takes place.

Answer (score 4):

Since closure reasons may change from time to time, this answer only reflects current time situation, which is 11 January 2014. Previous or new changes in the closure logic changes is not (and can not) reflected to the answer as it should be.

There is two separate objectives in this action:

1. Helping people
2. Doing your duty

Why SO and other SE sites exist? Because some people needs help and some can help them. From this point of view, doing your basic `duty` (maybe duty is not the correct word in here) in SE is help people if you can. so if you want to contribute, then help if you can.

Also, each SE site have its own moderation logic and rules. Since (most of the) rules are decided by the community itself and you are a part of the community, you can take part in those discussions to shape the community. But you must do your duty as it is, if you wish to contribute. If it is about closing a question and question do not fit, then you may feel yourself free to vote for closure even if you already answer it.

So two community duties on a cross-road right?

#### But whom to help

If question is self-descriptive and you know how to help. Then you can answer it if leaving a comment is not enough. Because helping people is important in here. But also this community do not accept some question prototypes. Let me explain with two examples:

- **Asking advice in choosing a tool** : This is opinion based and do not have a valid answer (since it may change from person to person). But I see no problem about giving your advice. Because Question owner needs some advice and you have yours. But also do your duty and vote for closure since it is *opinion based* and *answer may become lessly true in time*. In this form, it do not offer much *future reference to other users*. But do not forget, you may get upvotes, but as time passed and your answer became out-of-date, you may receive downvotes too.
- **Doing somebody else's homework**: Is it helping to that person? In fact no. S oyu can not count answering a such question as helping him *unless* you do not give a complete answer but show him how to solve it. Voting for closure -in fact- is helping him since you ask him do show some effort and try to do it and ask what he had tried.

So from this perspective, helping people ( by *answering* or *not answering*) who need help is the most important thing, second is doing one of your community duty and help community be better in shape and scope.

**But**, if you thing answering a such question will not help the person and is done just for *reputation*, then you can feel free not to up-vote or to down-vote a such answer. It is all up to you. Down-voting that answer might be right or wrong according to person but here is a community and everybody have his right to vote.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid I'm occasionally guilty of the behavior described.  I vote to close if I think the question should be closed/deleted, and I answer if I think I can be helpful (sometimes requiring "amusing" to be interpreted as a kind of helpfulness).  They're kind of independent considerations in my process.

I probably ought to mark community wiki if I vote to close, but I don't because I'm a big rep whore. (Though questions on the fast track to closing are rarely-to-never worth any rep to speak of, except for TheTXI who inexplicably seems able to harvest them like fruit ripe on the vine.  So maybe I'm only a medium rep whore.)

Answer (score 3):

You know, I just did this ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110686/proving-simple-addition)), and while I don't do it often, I don't think it's too inappropriate.  In particular, when something is inappropriate for SO, but there is a relatively straightforward and easy to compose answer, I figure the best way to go is to let them know the answer (if it's easy for me to answer), and also to let them know that SO isn't the right place to ask it.

Answer (score 3):

I sometimes vote to close as a hint or to start a discussion about whether something should be closed. As suggested I will put a comment like "as written this should be closed, but I suspect you want to know X (in which case please edit your question)" and I will answer X below. If the question is closed (normally because the user never returns) at least there's an answer to X, but if not there's an edit and something more to go on.

This may be semi-local to Bicycles where we get a lot of "here's a photo what do I do" and "based on a significant misunderstanding, how do I do {something silly}" questions. Often the eventual outcome is a decent question with a simple answer, but getting to it can be tedious, and new users rarely want to grind the tedium.

Close-and-answer is also one way to combat (other?) rep whores, because there's no point them vomiting in a stock answer to a duplicate question if there's already a CW answer in there. I think it would be better to penalise people who answer duplicate questions than simply null out the credit, but AFAIK we do the worst possible thing, leaving the answer and giving credit for it.

Answer (score 2):

> "it is totally hypocritical and seems almost like rep whoring (since often the closers answers are the only ones that remain to be voted on since no new answers can be given)."

You've answered your own question. Voting to close. (just kidding)

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand why some people answer and then vote to close. There is a loophole which some "rep whore"s try to exploit.

1. if someone starts writing an answer then Stack Exchange lets them publish it though the question is closed.
2. If a question is closed then the OP has the limited option to choose none or choose an answer from the existing answers.
3. I realized, if some question starts getting downvotes, then the OP might decide to accept an answer and get done with it.
4. There is no penalty for downvoting questions.

Fo me, it seems like the motivation behind a person to simultaneously vote to close the question, downvote the question and answer it is a strategy to be the only answer (or one of the few) in the question and/or have an accepted answer.

Comment: While there will probably be a few people that do this - I cannot prove that there are not - I don't think I've seen so much of this kind of action that I think it has become a problem on the site, to be honest. Then again, I don't often look at the main site of e.g. StackOverflow where a lot of low quality questions come in.