# Why can't one view upvotes cast by other users?

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

Why are users not allowed to view *upvotes* that other users have cast?

I know you can view what votes you have cast yourself, but on other users' profiles you can only see the totals.

I understand why downvotes would be hidden (so it's harder to take "revenge"...etc), but why are upvotes?

I'm not trying to make a feature request or suggestion, I'm just wondering about something that I couldn't find any other help on.

Comment: @downvoter, could you explain why you downvoted? I couldn't find an answer on this, and didn't see any harm in asking.

Comment: While you've labeled this as a discussion, it does come off as a feature request, or at least an argument for changing the current policy of voting being anonymous. This is likely where the down-votes come from - disagreement with you that this change would be a good idea.

Comment: Also, what does "not let there be" mean? Ban them from the site? I think you'll get a lot of argument from a lot of people if you tried to ban people like [Eric Lippert](http://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert), who has voted 1,005 times, but has only ever cast one up-vote (and I don't even know if that was on a question or an answer). Up-voting is a part of community interaction here, but it isn't a requirement.

Comment: P.S. [I forked that query to do something more closely resembling what you described](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/168195/214673/10k-users-with-very-few-up-votes).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I wasn't propsing anything, I was just wondering if there were a reason why viewing upvotes isn't enabled...I haven't been able to find anything on it, so that's why I asked. I guess some people didn't like that...

Comment: I think (as I mentioned above) it still comes off as a challenge to the current system (see [What's meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)). It could also be due to lack of research (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95603/why-are-votes-anonymous-lets-make-with-the-transparency-and-have-them-publicly) and also the "bandwagon effect" mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22771/the-answer-to-tactical-downvoting-problem/) - while these are mainly about down-votes, a lot of it can apply to up-votes too; lack of up-vote may viewed like a down-vote).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thanks for helping. I wasn't trying to challenge anything, I just was unable to find any information about this. How could I word it not to sound challenging? BTW, I wasn't suggesting anything about banning users, I was just using that to show a possible positive influence of being able to view votes.

Comment: I think with a lot less commentary about "the only harm" and suggesting that changing it would make people more likely to up-vote.

Comment: So is that edit better? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: I think it should be even more concise. Answerers don't need to know how long you've been wondering about this problem; it doesn't change the answer. Also the commentary about down-votes etc. doesn't belong in the question. Sorry this doesn't seem to have made your situation any better; I think the influx of downvotes are just the Monday morning crowd seeing your question for the first time (and it may have been worse in its original state).

Comment: Ok, thanks for editing it. That's the last time I ask a question Sunday night. Just to be clear, though, isn't Meta where I can ask questions about the site? I understand why questions where someone rants about something are downvoted, but I thought this was just asking about something that there's no help on an no one's asked before.

Comment: I am only speculating as to why people have down-voted. If you want the real reasons, you'll have to ask them; of course, they'll have to let you know, since voting is anonymous. I'm not sure if that's ironic or not.

Comment: Haha, yeah. Thanks for helping me try to understand this (this is the first question I have asked that's received more downvotes that upvotes).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Frankly, it's not really anyone else's business which posts I've up-voted. For one, let's say a question has two answers, and I up-voted one but didn't up-vote the other (or the other got a down-vote, maybe by me, or maybe by someone else). It would make it easier for the author of the answer I *didn't* up-vote to deduce that I didn't up-vote his/her post, and perhaps even that I down-voted it. The way I see it, this makes it *more* likely to cause vengeful behavior.

Also, it's not your job to detect sock puppets, and I don't see how this will make it any easier - moderators already have more access to information about suspicious voting patterns than this would provide to you, and it's probably not constructive to have more tattle-tailing causing more work for them...

Comment: I had just put in the part about sock puppets because I knew moderators are busy, and I thought users could then flag or post on meta when they think there's a sock puppet to help the mods. But, you're right. That would lead to tattle-tail and revengeful behavior.

Answer (score 9):

> Why are users not allowed to view upvotes that other users have cast?

Many reasons, 1 as you stated:

> a user upvoting someone simply because that user upvoted them

This reason on it's own is enough not to show them.
The site works well, vote as required based on question's and answer's own merits.

"Friendly" upvotes will spoil various things, such as the accuracy of a question or answer's value.

As well as users revenge downvoting because they didn't upvote - you answer a question, get an upvote or two, and see that the questioner didn't upvote you.

You revenge downvote them, they revenge remove your answer as accepted, etc, etc.

Even where people are savvy and don't do the above, there will be comments "hey questioner, why didn't you upvote me as I helped you..."

However unlikely you may think this and other issues are, think of millions of users all with different attitudes and morals and moods all seeing who's upvoted who....

Moderators cannot even see who has cast votes, only totals, which we see at 1k rep.