# Is there a way to report drive-by downvotes?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I'm a bit new to SO and I'm trying to build some points. I noticed some [driveby downvotes, or suspect some users possibly trying to hog an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548554/how-to-select-cell-using-jquery-id-selector/21548596#21548596).

Could someone point me to a reporting tool for situations like this?

NOTE: This is ***not*** about serial downvotes.

---

**Update:** It looks like someone (a good samaritan, perhaps?) upvoted the answer in the referenced SO question. I'll have to make the situation more clear here.

I provided an answer to a SO question, an answer which was downvoted. When I noticed that many people were competing for the answer spot, and that another user had the exact same answer as I had, I felt my answer may have been downvoted by a careless or possibly jealous user wanting to bubble up his own answer and hide competing answers.

I wanted to know if it was possible to have mods look into cases of unfair downvotes, as a long-term concern for me if I wanted to get involved on SO, especially when some of my answers took me more than 2 hours to provide.

Luckily enough, Bart provided some reassurance below.

Comment: Voting is anonymous, and isolated downvotes without explanation are a fact of life. The moderators won't act on a single example. If you have a number of downvotes close together there is an automated script that reverses that sort of voting fraud. If your concern doesn't match either of these scenarios flag an affected post for moderator attention and explain your concern.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is nothing to report there really. Just live with them. And with that, you don't need a tool to report anything.

If you are the victim of serial downvotes (downvotes targeted at you, not your content, in a large quantity) then there are tools in place to automatically detect and reverse that. See [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: Thanks Bart. For example, this OP was downvoted 3 times. I understand now that it was in the wrong forum initially. This is more of a long-term concern than just for this thread.

I went over the article you sent me and my understanding is that if I feel there is a voting fraud to my detriment, I should wait 24 hours before becoming concerned (flagging for a moderator) and could in the meantime visit the meta tavern for a mod to just give it a check.

Another thing that confuses me is, is the meta tavern where mods look at questions, or is meta a place for mods, and if so why I'm at -3 here.

Comment: Both Meta and chat (the Tavern) are open to all users. So while there are plenty of mods here keeping an eye on things, it's not just moderators. The same goes for the Tavern. Plenty of regular users there as well. You will need 20rep though (afaik) to be able to enter there. And just to be clear (but I guess you understood) the single downvote you received is not serial downvoting. So contacting a mod about that is of no use. As for the downvotes you received here I can only guess. Perhaps some think it's a question you could have trivially found the answer to. I didn't downvote so don't know

Comment: Like you said it's not really a duplicate (I can't upvote your comment yet), so I'm let down. I guess my real question then is why can only serial downvotes/upvotes be flagged and say a jealous user trying to get his answer to bubble up is not punished for affecting the time you put in an answer. In the case in OP, the answer I offered didn't take me too much time, but in other cases it can take me up to 2 hours to offer a good reply. I would hate it if that happened. To demonstrate why I think that happened here, there is another identical answer in the original qtn that wasn't downvoted.

Comment: Don't go guessing at who downvoted you. In practice it turns out you're most likely wrong. But even if you aren't, moderators are not there to judge the accuracy of votes. However a user votes is up to that user. Up or down, for whatever reason. Hopefully that's a correct one, but on occasion it's not. It happens. Moderators will not interfere with that. In fact, they couldn't interfere with that, even if they wanted. Moderators don't have access to voting data. They can't see who voted for what. We all get the occasional strange downvote. But if your answer is good, you'll get more upvotes.

Comment: Okay, thanks for reassuring me. With 44.4k points I'm inclined to trust your experience. I'll just take this OP (at -3) and my other downvote as a stroke of bad luck.

Comment: Downvotes on meta mean that people don't like the idea that you're proposing (such as a way to report a downvote that isn't part of a pattern).

Comment: @happyD This case sounds more like [tactical downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22771/the-answer-to-tactical-downvoting-problem?rq=1) than serial downvoting to me.  (I don't see a more recent topic with a clear resolution though, but it may give you a start on what to look for.)

Comment: @Troyen. This is exactly what I was concerned about. Thanks for showing me that article and for reassuring me that I wasn't just being paranoid, and that it's an actual problem people have weighed on. Some of the solutions proposed there are things I was thinking about myself (not let people downvote an answer if they are competing for the selected answer, e.g. if they provided an answer themselves).

Comment: @Matthew Lundberg. Then it's funny that the article linked by Troyen shows an upvote of 28 and 6 favorites.