# Voting lock mechanism for near simultaneous answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, voting

I have the following scenario:
A question was made and now 2 users start writing an answer before the other ever posted it. 
Then the first user press the post button and later the other user. 
But now the first user down vote the second answer, just because.

Now i would ask if it yould be possible to implement a mechanism, that locks the option to down vote the other answer just because it was posted to the same time (e.g. under 2 min)

I think it would improve the user experience, if that pointless down voting, to get the own answer to a higher rating, would not be not possible.

It happend to me multiple times, that I start writing an answer to a fresh question and then post it just a couple of seconds after another post an answer and this other user down voted my answer without a obvious reason, besides to get rid of the competitors.

Comment: This is known as [tactical downvoting, and has been recognized as a problem for a long while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22771/the-answer-to-tactical-downvoting-problem). But this could use some more explanation of the ways this proposal avoids problems, such as cases where someone writes a correct answer, sees an incorrect answer also posted, and wants to downvote it.

Comment: If an answer is incorrect also other will down vote it and if the competitor think it is wrong he can also comment it, what is wrong.

Comment: @Horitsu - So I submit an answer, to a question you already answered, and I think your answer is incorrect and/or low quality.  All I need to do is submit a comment that says "cowabunga dude" and then issue the downvote?  Requiring a comment to issue a downvote is pointless, it's not possible, to automatically parse a comment, to verify it makes sense in the context of voting.

Comment: I will no longer discuss on here, since in the linked question about the tactical down votes is everything said. Feel free to vote to close this question since it is a duplicate as I registered some times after i asked it.

Answer (score 3):

> Then the first user presses the post button and later the other user. But now the first user downvote the second answer, just because.

How do you know this happened?

> I think it would improve the user experience, if that pointless downvoting, to get the own answer to a higher rating, would not be possible.

How does downvoting another answer increase the rating of your answer? How long would the voting be locked? What prevents the other user from waiting until the lock expires?  *I assume you would want a lockout on all voting, since upvotes are as important, as downvotes.*

> It happened to me multiple times, that I start writing an answer to a fresh question and then post it just a couple of seconds after another post an answer and this other user downvoted my answer without an obvious reason, besides to get rid of the competitors.

You only suspect this has happened to you.  You don't actually know if any of the users who submitted an answer to that question actually downvoted your answer.  Voting is anonymous, this type of thing is the exact reason, that is the case.