# What's the policy against voting to close and answering at the same time?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closing Etiquette: Why Do Some Answer *and* Close?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4283/closing-etiquette-why-do-some-answer-and-close)

How do you feel about voting to close a question *and* answering the question at the same time?

Let's say I vote to close a question as a duplicate, but I am not sure if my opinion will be shared by four other people. Should I answer the question if I know the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is no policy.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4283/closing-etiquette-why-do-some-answer-and-close)

Some avoid it.

Other do it, holding out the justification that (a) it might help the OP and (b) the close might not actually happen.

// and I answered first, then went and found the above linked alleged duplicate afterward. So I'm guilty this time, even though I am usually in the the *"don't do it"* camp.

Answer (score 4):

Add your answer to the question you link to as the "master" - assuming that it's not a duplicate answer of course.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know but I'm gonna try it now