# Is it bad form to answer a question and then immediately cast the final closing vote?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, etiquette

Just wonder if the community thinks this is "taking advantage".

Comment: Related but more general: [Closing Etiquette: Why Do Some Answer \*and\* Close?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4283/closing-etiquette-why-do-some-answer-and-close)

Answer (score 15):

It shouldn't matter whether it's the first or the final close vote. Answering and closevoting at the same time is either the right thing to do (not so often) or the wrong thing (often).

If you really feel you have a strong case for doing it, do it. It's not unimaginable: for example,

- one might want to close a qeustion for being "too broad" or"unclear", but still help the user out because one has a hunch about what they want. (This is appropriate in very special cases only, though. If the question is bad and simply needs fixing, don't enable the user by providing an answer anyway.)
- one might want to give a slightly more specific answer to a question that really is a duplicate.

But make sure it's really appropriate, and you have a good valid answer to a question that isn't completely off topic on Stack Overflow.

Also consider making your answer Community Wiki.

Comment: +1, was going to say the exact same thing, but you were both faster and more thorough. :)

Comment: If I make my answer Community Wiki, doesn't that mean the question effectively _isn't_ closed, because anyone can answer it by editing my answer?

Comment: @RobinGreen: Anyone (with a bit of rep) can edit or post comments anyway. The point of marking your answer as CW is that votes on CW answers won't give you any rep. Thus, you're not benefiting from your "unfair advantage".

Comment: I don't think Community Wiki is supposed be abused for rep-denial - even if it's often used that way.

Comment: Isn't it a bad idea to answer an unclear or broad question? You're rewarding the person for asking a poor question, and giving them no need to edit their question to meet our standards.

Comment: @Mysticial is there previous discussion on using CW to deny rep? I do that all the time and I don't see how it's abuse, but I'm open to arguments

Comment: @probablyPekka Can't remember. I remember seeing something about, "CW is for true community collaboration - not a tool to deny people rep." But I guess if you interpret it differently, you're free to deny yourself rep, but you shouldn't go forcing it on others.

Comment: @Mysticial oh, using it to deny *others* rep stinks, yeah. That's not a part of the discussion here though, is it?

Comment: @probablyPekka Right. I only remembered that part when I tried to think back to where I saw it. So fair enough. The rep-denial argument doesn't apply here.

Comment: I've done this a number of times for the reason behind your second bullet, but usually because I realize that the duplicate I voted for actually does not have a good answer (and often this is because it is relevant for previous versions of the software, but not current ones). Of course these days I can retract my close vote; that wasn't always the case.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that questions that are going to be closed should not be answered if there's a valid reason for closing them. I know it sometimes feels cruel as you know the answer and you could help OP but this doesn't help SO to maintain the high standard.

If those questions keep on receiving answers, what's the point of closing them? They stay on the site, people get reputation, etc. There's no deterrent from asking those questions. If stick to the rule and not answer them, people will learn to follow the rules (at least, to some extent).

Answer (score 2):

Answering questions which are candidates for closure encourages undesirable behavior.

Overall it is probably best to just close it and move on to more deserving questions.

However, there are those rare occasions where it can make sense. After all, this is a question **and** answer site ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say in that last sentence.