# Can I replace a closed question which has no answers or comments?

Tags: support, edits, closed-questions

If I have a closed question with no answers or comments, can I edit the question enough that I make it an entirely different and better question?

Comment: Related, (maybe dupe?), but from the opposite perspective [Rolling back a completely changed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64459/rolling-back-a-completely-changed-question)

Comment: Another related discussion: [Author's edit right in on-hold question vs invalidating existing answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302373/authors-edit-right-in-on-hold-question-vs-invalidating-existing-answers).

Comment: "still on-topic" > If your original question was already on-topic, why even consider editing it to something entirely different instead of just fixing the other issues with it, such as narrowing it down or adding the lacking details?

Comment: Gues it beter then to ask a new question with all that improovements, since it will be then a more or les diferent question then the original.

Comment: Related (for a different situation): *[Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/)*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No you shouldn't. You can try to *fix* the question, but the fundamentals of the question should be the same.

People voted for the question you asked already, and editing it to something different is confusing

Comment: Plus, if you don't want your original question to stick around, you can delete it. If it's closed and has no answers or comments, the community's probably not losing any meaningful content from you deleting it.

Comment: I feel like the best advice to give here is "think very hard before you post" but I never quite worked out how to fit it into the answer. Also deletions count against question bans too

Comment: @V2Blast however in case question has negative score that would have impact towards a question ban on the site, so better fix it by editing than deleting.

Comment: Assuming its salvagable - and even if it was it would be a question on the same topic, not a rewrite. I'm not sure if lots of downvotes or deletes would be worse

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard: Definitely better to edit it into shape than delete it entirely... but as JG says, sometimes it's not salvageable.

Comment: I have mixed feelings about this. Sure, it's bad to edit a question into a totally different one, if that invalidates existing answers. But if the question literally has no answers, I don't see the harm. If the edit invalidates comments, they can be flagged as No Longer Needed. IMHO, it's better to recycle an otherwise unsalvageable question than to delete it and increase your risk of a question ban. I don't know the stats, but we often get question-banned users on meta SO & meta Physics who've fixed their old fixable questions, but they're still banned because of their unfixable ones.