# Is there a way to get a question off the unanswered list if it's answered in a comment?

Tags: support, specific-question, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to handle questions which are answered in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-to-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments)

The user who posted this question promptly realized her simple mistake and posted a comment with the obvious answer. But the question has been on the unanswered list for ages now. Is there any good way to get it cleared up and off the list?

[PDO 'LIKE' query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552506/pdo-like-query)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Post the answer (preferably as a community wiki post, since the asker was the one who figured it out) and wait for someone to upvote it.

Comment: For answers discovered later by dint of effort while waiting for SO to help, I don't feel there is any need for CW. This is different (at least in my view) from answers prepared as the question was being written and posted promptly as a FYI service.

Comment: @dmckee - I think this is more about giving appropriate credit. If the answer was posted as a comment, you can go back and repost it as an answer yourself, but don't try to earn rep for someone else's work.

Comment: @Joel: Ah. Missed that. Yes, CW when it's someone else' work.