# How to handle an answer as a comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to handle questions which are answered in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-to-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments)

Someone answered a question of mine in a comment. How do I handle the situation? I don't want to leave the question open.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Leave a comment asking them to post their comment as an answer so you can accept it. You can notify them by using the [@username syntax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/lets-make-it-easier-to-reply-within-comments/35917#35917) in your comment.

Comment: if this fails, just leave an answer yourself and accept it ...

Comment: The person who wrote the question should still be able to do it so that they get some rep.