# Comments that solve the problem

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to handle questions which are answered in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-to-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments)
>   [How to avoid unanswered questions with answers in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130370/how-to-avoid-unanswered-questions-with-answers-in-comments)

Recently, I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772847/imports-working-with-raw-file-but-not-in-idle) on SO, and the answer was provided in a comment.

Because of statistics and semantics and all that lot, solved questions should be marked as accepted. But how do I mark it as this when it's a comment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid unanswered questions with answers in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130370/how-to-avoid-unanswered-questions-with-answers-in-comments) and [How to handle questions which are answered in the comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-to-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments)

Comment: I answer questions in a comment when 1) I'm not sure of the answer and 2) I suspect I'm going to get into a back and forth discussion before I find out what the real question is.  Especially in a subject like Java, where students want their homework done in the months of April, May, November, and December.

Answer (score 4):

You don't. Just leave a comment asking the user to make it an answer. If the user is unresponsive, you could even make it an answer yourself after a while and just accept that.

Comment: A fellow user did say "JF deserves to put up the answer and get the green tick", and "JF" was @tagged.

Comment: Then wait a little while (The question seems only a day old) until he has a chance to do so. But if he doesn't in the end, there's nothing wrong with doing it yourself.

Comment: @ACarter - If you left a comment asking the op to leave as an answer, then you've done your due diligence. ;)  If he/she really feels like adding an answer, then he/she will come back and do so.