# Answers given ONLY in comment - how to avoid low accept rate?

Tags: support, comments, answers, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid unanswered questions with answers in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130370/how-to-avoid-unanswered-questions-with-answers-in-comments)

Hi How can I accept answer which is given in comment only ? Looks like there is no option to do that and it affects my accept rate...

Comment: If the only answer to your question is in the comments, then that doesn't count against your accept rate.  Either way, ask the commenter to change his/her comment into an answer, or you could self-answer the question if the commenter never returns.

Comment: @jonsca answered this question in a Comment...

Comment: @anDroider Just for the sheer irony.  It didn't start out that way, but let's retrofit it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't worry too much about your accept rate. It really isn't that big a deal, and if anyone gives you a hard time about it in comments, just flag those comments as non-constructive and a moderator will take care of those.

You have asked a total of 8 questions on Stack Overflow, accepted answers for 5, you are doing just fine in any case!

As for the answer in a comment; you can reply to that and ask if the poster wants to make that a full answer that you can accept. If there is no response in a few days, go ahead and post it yourself and accept that!

The point of Stack Overflow is that there are great questions that hopefully get answers, so that others on the wider internet can benefit from those answers too. Not just you, not just whomever answered, but the wider community of software developers around the world. Those reputation points are just a way to encourage the quality of the questions and answers, but they are kind of optional.

Comment: +1 for in depth clarification.