# Turn Comment into Community Wiki answer or downvote question for community deletion?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, community-wiki

I visit the encryption tag on SO and use the Unanswered tab to pick Questions to answer. In [RSA-Algorithm Invalid Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763662/rsa-algorithm-invalid-keys) I do not know how to proceed.

Should I make a Community Wiki Answer from the Comment by CodesInChaos like it is stated in [How to avoid unanswered questions with answers in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130370/how-to-avoid-unanswered-questions-with-answers-in-comments)? SO told me I cannot upvote the answer I just posted (I deleted it already) so it would further stay in Unanswered : (

Reading [Enable automatic deletion of old, unanswered zero-score questions after a year?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) I have another option: If I downvote the question it would get deleted by the community user. As the question shows some work and provides a programming related answer I am not sure this is justified.

If my evaluation of the question / answer is not correct and this question is either clearly worthless or valuable please say so; But I would still like to know how to remove questions from "Unanswered" that are valuable and abandoned at the same time.

Comment: Follow [animuson's advice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130374/162704), and start by asking CodesInChaos to turn their comment into an answer. If they aren't interested or don't respond at all, feel free to post an answer yourself. It's completely up to you if you'll wikify it or not, but please do give credit to CodesInChaos in your answer. Don't worry about not being able to upvote the answer, someone else will (by posting an answer, you bump the question and bring new attention to it).

Comment: I "answer" in comments pretty often, since I believe that answers should have a higher quality level than comments. In this case I'd expect an answer to actually pinpoint the problem, instead of just a wild guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step 1: is this question worth keeping? What use would this question be to future visitors?

The question contains no code, but links to about 150 lines of non-self-contained code. At best, that's a huge dump to debug, which isn't very useful. Apart from the code, there are a few sample inputs and outputs.

Based on the sample inputs and outputs, CodeInChaos determined which part of the code was likely to be wrong. How is this going to help anyone else? Merely realizing that the results point to a mistake in the same place requires as much analysis as figuring out in which way the results are wrong and thus where the mistake in the code is.

So no, this question isn't likely to help anyone else.

Close it and move on.

(Step 2 would be deciding whether to ask CodeInChaos to post an answer, or posting an answer yourself, but we aren't reaching step 2 in this instance.)