# What to do about a comment that correctly answers my question by linking to a duplicate?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, answers-as-comments

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074266/xcode-4-3-2-crashing-on-source-editing) and an answer was given in comments. The answer was a pointer to another question, and my question is a duplicate of one. There are a few problems here.

First, should I delete this question or not? If yes, how can I do this? If no, is there way to close this question and mark the comment as the answer?

Maybe there's a more general question here -- if the answer is made in a comments, can I somehow transform it to an answer or mark the comment as the accepted answer?

What should I do if I found that the right answer is given in a comment? How can I indicate that the problem is solved and close the question in such a case?

Comment: Here we go Meta; take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-to-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments

Comment: @JacquesCousteau - Not quite the duplicate, as this one has the added issue of what do to with a duplicate question to begin with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the question is a genuine duplicate and it has not gotten any answers yet, you can simply delete it - there is a delete link just under the tags.

Consider simply voting to close - there is a close reason that allow you to select the duplicate answer. The benefits of this - closing vs deleting is that your question remains on the site and can be found and will then have links to the duplicates with answers.

If you believe it isn't and should remain on the site, but you have gotten an answer as a comment, you can ask the commenter to make the comment into an answer.

Comment: I'd say you should vote to close and/or flag as duplicate rather than simply deleting. Unless the title and body of the original are so close as to be unlikely to act as a separate search target.

Comment: @JacquesCousteau - How do you flag as duplicate?

Comment: @Oded: when you don't have enough rep to vote for close, then the close options in the "it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate" section of the flag dialog can be used, but they don't account as a close vote.

Comment: Just write a message to the mods "I asked this question, somebody pointed out that it's a dupe, they're right, please close". There's also (if I remember correctly) flag link -> This doesn't belong here -> exact duplicate.