# Is answering closed questions via comments allowed?

Tags: support, comments, closed-questions, answers-as-comments

When a question is closed, you can still comment on it. Say that you know the answer to the question. Are you allowed to answer it in a comment?

Comment: Old near-duplicate which got the opposite answer: [General policies on answering closed questions in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176961/)

Comment: As can be seen by the answers on the duplicate and the answers here, there doesn't seem to be single 'right' answer to this question. Some sites will leave such comments until the question is deleted by the automatic cleanup processes, some sites will delete them as 'that's not what comments are for' and 'it discourages editing the post into shape or asking a good question to begin with'. It also doesn't matter if a question is closed or open, on some sites comments 'hinting' at answers are deleted on sight, on others they're welcomed...