# Marking question answered if the answer occurs in the comments section?

Tags: feature-request

I've begun noticing questions that look unanswered to the standard "answered" interface, but in the question area an answer was provided fully in the form a comment or several comments.

Protocol for handling this issue was discussed here in 2010: [How should I handle questions which are answered in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-should-i-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments)

A potential solution to the problem was offered (and declined) here in 2009:
[Mark a comment as answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question)

Looking at instances where this happens it usually involves a very short answer, a simple solution, a link out, or a conversation where the answer is acheived during member interactions in the comments (there's an example here: [Look up Column number in a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12038186/look-up-column-number-in-a-range#))

The interface is designed intentionally so that comments cannot be marked as correct answers, and marking an individual comment as a correct answer would sometimes be inappropriate or impossible (because the answer is distributed). However, there is a real need for questions answered like this to be marked as answered: the interface improperly shows the question as unanswered (leading users who may know the answer to open it needlessly, and users who may need the answer to skip the question when it could solve their issue).

So I have a feature request:

Allows the member who asked the question (or moderators and super-users) to mark a question as answered even if there are no answers provided outside of the comments field. I don't know exactly how this would be best implemented, but it would ideally allow comments that contribute to the answer to be (optionally) highlighted so that later viewers can quickly find the key bits in a long string of comments. I think such a feature would be a real improvement for the StackOverflow interface and the value of the site.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-should-i-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/54718?lq=1

Comment: @random: Thanks for pointing me to that. I couldn't find it when I searched last night. I have edited my question to a feature request and believe it is no longer a duplicate: this is something that should be addressed in the interface, either in the way I suggest or in some other way. Protocol is not doing the trick.