# A new button "solved" in questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments

When we're searching for an unanswered question, we're faced with thousand of finished questions, but unanswered, because there was a conversation via comments.

A good new feature would be to add a "finished" or "solved" button, this button could appear only if someone commented, where moderators or the owner could press, but the question would be open for new comments or answers.

Comment: See also [How should I handle questions which are answered in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718)

Comment: A new button `Add [SOLVED!!!] to title`. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is asking for trouble; comments are a problematic way to store answers, as they...

- ...can't be edited
- ...can't be downvoted
- ...can't be searched for
- ...can't be accepted (thus marking the question as answered)
- ...don't mark a question as answered *even when heavily upvoted*
- ...*can* be deleted rather easily
- ...always display in chronological order
- ...do little to prevent the question *itself* from being deleted (by the author or others)
- ...are a pain to read for anything non-trivial

Best course of action when you find one of these questions is to... Post an answer. Take whatever information is in the comments, and put it in an actual answer. Then if that answer proves useful, it can be upvoted or accepted (which marks the question answered), in addition to addressing all the other deficiencies present in the list above.

Best part? You don't need to be a moderator to do this; literally *anyone* can take this step, including people who don't even have accounts.