# What's the etiquette when a comment leads me to an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, etiquette

I posted a question on Stack Overflow and another user's ("User Y") comment led me to a solution.

I replied to User Y and asked them to submit their comment as an answer, in which case I'll happily accept it. However, after several days, the only answer (from another user) is a (polite) version of "your question is silly, you should just do X instead. If you really must do what you asked, User Y's comment is the way to go."

I could now write out a detailed answer, inspired by User Y's comment. However, I feel that User Y should get credit for this answer. A generally useful answer would require a little more detail, but not really all that much.

What's the etiquette here? My question has a few upvotes and favourites, so it seems I'm not the only one who thinks it's useful to the community. How long should I wait before answering my own question?

Comment: Good question, largely addressed at [How should I handle questions which are answered in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-should-i-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments)