# Why are we using a comment box as an answer box sometimes?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some people answer in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments)

Sometimes I have seen that somebody are using a comment box as an answer box here.
Is it the right way to put an answer over there?

Comment: Can you give an example? The comment box is generally for *comments*, things that don't qualify as complete answers to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Speaking personally I'll use a comment if

a) I'm not 100% sure that my answer is correct.
b) I'm posting a hint rather than the full answer.

This is apart from using comments to try to elicit more information from the poster (their intended use).

Others will have different reasons.

This applies (for me) too all sites not just Meta.