# Why do users sometimes post solutions as comments rather than answers?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some people answer in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments)

I have noticed it's fairly common for users to add a comment to a question rather than posting their solution as an answer which could be accepted for points. Because of this, I sometimes worry that I'm violating protocol by posting an answer.

What I refer to are not requests for clarification, but genuine answers which often do go on to receive many *comment* votes.

Why is this done?

(Note: My experience is mostly on Stack Overflow, but I will assume other sites are similar.)