# answer as comment

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some people answer in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments)

What's the reason this is done?

I've seen several questions with valid answers hidden in comments. And I found reasons why people use answer for commenting, but not for the other way round.

Comment: It's just more fun to comment instead of answering.

Comment: Sometimes people don't see a question being worth an answer. Or they are guessing. Or they have part of an answer. Or they want to help but don't have the time for a full answer.

Comment: You can't downvote comments

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - No, but you can un-upvote!

Comment: @Oded No you can't. Comment votes are permanent.

Comment: [And, before you ask, read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question)

Comment: @Telthien - [really?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment)

Comment: @Telthien not for the first minute

Comment: @Doorknob I have never been able to reverse them - even after days. I've tried, too, to reverse a couple stupid upvotes. Doesn't work.

Comment: @Telthien No, the point is you can only reverse them **for the first minute**

Comment: @Doorknob And what I am saying is that I, personally, have never been able to reverse them.

Comment: @Doorknob I just tried to go back and reverse a comment upvote. It didn't work. Don't know if this is local to me, but it doesn't bother me too much.

Comment: Within the first minute, but not the first 5 seconds

Comment: Is there really a time out for comments