# Comment or Answer, which one to choose?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some people answer in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments)

I see some people actually gave the answer to the question, but they posted it in comments, also I see reverse of it, they commented as an answer to asker.

I can understand why some people try to comment as an answer, but why some people answer in comments? Is there anything useful in answering as a comment? Is there some points I'm missing?

Also is there a good write-up/guide for choosing to answer or comment for anyone who want to help/answer?

Thanks