# Should the [dll-hell] tag be a valid tag on SO?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

I recently noticed the [dll-hell](/questions/tagged/dll-hell) tag on SO and was curious if this was a valid tag? If this is a valid tag, then would other tags such as [wcf-hell](/questions/tagged/wcf-hell), [wpf-hell](/questions/tagged/wpf-hell), etc... be valid as well? Granted the examples are not commonplace in every day developer verbiage such as [dll-hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell).

Comment: Since these other terms are not nearly as common, couldn't that account entirely for why we don't have (and don't need, and shouldn't have) those other tags?

Comment: As you apparently already know, "DLL Hell" refers to a very specific phenomenon. Making the comparison between [tag:wcf-hell] and [tag:dll-hell] is an attempt at an argument by absurdity. Of course we wouldn't allow those other tags, because "WCF/WPF Hell" is not a term with a specific, well-established meaning. Having the discussion about the necessity of the [tag:dll-tag] is reasonable, but the way you've phrased the question poisons the well, so to speak.

Comment: @CodyGray Well, it's [a cluster of phenomena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dll_hell).

Comment: I think it should just be synonymized with [tag:dll]. It's a meta tag describing that they're having problems with DLL files. I just don't see how it's different enough to warrant a separate tag.

Comment: @CodyGray Great [Comment-Answer!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments/133286)

Comment: It's not an answer. I specifically left the debate about whether we should have a [tag:dll-hell] tag open. I don't feel strongly about that. I just think the question has a biased presentation. (cc @bobo)

Comment: Great article for clarification on [what exactly is meant by dll-hell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.01.windowsconfidential.aspx)

Comment: @robertharvey what's been `completed` ?

Comment: Synonymized to [dll].

Answer (score 2):

I don't think such witty slang names for tags are constructive on StackOverflow. It's like there would be tag [fear-driven-development](/questions/tagged/fear-driven-development) on Workspace.SE. They are commonly used, they are well understood, but they do not form constructive questions.

You should ask question about how to manage library dependencies and not to complain that you have problems with it. Using terms like DLL-hell sounds like complaining.