# Question already answered by a comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers

I was wondering if someone else has the problem that a question might be already answered by a comment. I mainly focus on questions that don't have any answer already in order to help.

It costs me a great amount of time to read the question and the comments on order to realise it's already answered by a comment. Is there a way to skip such questions? And if not, could it be implemented 'answered by comments' or something like that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some people answer in comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/why-do-some-people-answer-in-comments)

Comment: Well, not really. My question is about the possibilty to ignore questions that are answered in a comment.

Comment: @gnat yes, thank you that's what i was looking for.

Comment: And now we have a comment that answered my question :)

Comment: @jeb. in many cases questions answered through comments are cases of questions that are too broad or not complete in themselves - perhaps the question closure should be studied in that cases.

Answer (score 5):

People shouldn't be answering in comments. I'd actually take the opportunity to post a *full* answer and closing the loop as far as the question goes, rather than leaving the answer to languish in the comments

Comment: I agree, but it is a fact that many people answer in a comment on a daily basis. It would be great if it would be possible to mark the question 'Answered by comment' or have some way to make it visual that the question is answered.

Comment: We absolutely want to discourage that. If people are doing it on a daily basis, they ought not to