# making a comment an answer

Tags: feature-request, answers, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Promoting comments to answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49563/promoting-comments-to-answers)
>   [Allow converting comments to answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51899/allow-converting-comments-to-answers)

Have you ever considered the posibility to set a comment as an answer?

Sometimes a user gives interesting information, even an answer in a comment, could we have a way to link an answer to the interesting comment or a way of converting comments into answers?

Comment: Related: [Allow converting comments to answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51899/allow-converting-comments-to-answers) and [Mark a comment as answer to a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a feature for that we can do it manually.

If you face this situation (someone answer your question via comment), ask that commentator to convert his/her comment into an answer so that you can accept it.

If he/she does not reply you or does not make an answer, you can make an answer with linking that comment and make that answer CW because it is not only your effort.