# Question comments as question answers

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I handle questions which are answered in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-should-i-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments)
>   [Allow converting comments to answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51899/allow-converting-comments-to-answers)

I found many questions with no answers but with many valuable comments. In many cases one or more of those comments could be a question answer.

I think it would be great feature if a question author could also tag one of the comments as a question answer.

Server side functionality then would present that comment similar way as answer (or copy the comment to an answer slot) and grand adequate reputation points to a question and comment authors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see a recent comment that is an answer, reply to it and request the user to post it as an answer. If there is no response, or it seems unlikely the original author will follow through, post an answer with this content yourself.