# Convert comment to answer

Tags: feature-request, comments, convert-to-answer

Sometimes comments are helpful enough to be considered answer.

What do you think about a button or something that allows to convert a comment into an answer?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51899/allow-converting-comments-to-answers?rq=1