# What’s the difference between the tags [convert-to-comment] and [answers-as-comments]?

Tags: support, tags, meta

I found it weird, there are two tags [convert-to-comment](/questions/tagged/convert-to-comment) and [answers-as-comments](/questions/tagged/answers-as-comments).

I have looked the tag wiki given, I found that these two tags mean the same things, that is “For questions related to converting answers to comments” and another one is “ For issues related to comments that should have been answers”.

I don’t know what is the differences between these two tags, maybe we need to create tag synonyms for them?

Comment: The tag wikis and tag excerpts for these tags haven't changed since at least 2022. While there could be more explanation, particularly that there's no tag wiki for the [tag:answers-as-comments] tag, the excerpts make it clear that they are for opposite situations.

Comment: Note: while I did downvote, it was to show disagreement with the proposal that the two tags should be synonyms.

Comment: It would help if you could explain what made you feel that the two tags meant the same thing. Without an explanation as to what you found to make it seem like they were the same, it's difficult to edit the tag wikis and excerpts to remove that confusion. So, getting a bit more information from you would help us to be able to make the site better for people in the future.

Comment: @Makyen I wrote wrong yesterday , is comments as answers, not answers and comments. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, but given that you've received an answer under the old version of the question, your recent edit invalidates that answer. I understand you may have mistyped the tags, but since you got an answer, I've had to roll back your edit.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog So I need to ask another question right?

Comment: Or, the question I edited is still duplicated ones?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

Convert to comment is the action of converting existing answer, after already posted, to a comment, which can be done either by a moderator manually, or automatically under some circumstances.

Answers as comments is about comments, which try to answer the question, or fitting as answers. This is not about actual answers, it is about the comments.

So you can consider those tags even as opposite: answer posted as comment should become answer, and answer which isn't really an answer can/should be converted to become a comment. (There is no "convert to answer" yet, and yes [it has been asked before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51899/allow-converting-comments-to-answers).)

Comment: So ask a new question, and please try to check it twice and even more to see if that is the question you meant to ask.