# New ways of ending the question -- solved by myself, solved by comment

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

OK, for me it is pretty obvious, but Stack Exchange still does not have such features:

- I asked a question and a week later I found an answer -- I would like to edit the question to add section "solution" and mark question as solved (not closed though)
- I asked a question, and somebody commented:

  > hey, why don't you use foo and bar?

which appears to be a perfect solution -- thus I would like to mark a COMMENT as THE answer; it would be nice, if the Stack Exchange engine automagically ripped off that comment and put it as an answer (reply).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first point is already possible: Just answer the question yourself, and mark it as accepted.

You could also reply to the commenter with something like "Thanks @abcd, that was indeed the solution; why don't you write an answer so I can give you the reps?", and wait for a day or two for them to respond; if they don't, write it up yourself.

Answering your own question is perfectly acceptable (no pun intended).

As for your second point, that is indeed a duplicate: [Mark a comment as answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question)

Comment: Thank you. This is always "funny" reading such answer "you can't, and this is by design". Oh, well, world if full of open minds ;-)

Comment: @macias: It's also always "funny" reading such comments implying other people do *not* have an open mind because they disagree ;-)

Comment: To extend on the first point a bit: these Q&A sites are not some personal help fora (forums), and accepting answers is not the same as "we're done, nothing to see here, move on". It really doesn't matter for future visitors if one answered their own question or if someone else offered the best solution. So indeed: no need for some "solved by myself" indicator.