# Way to convert a comment to an answer?

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mark a comment as answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question)

Some time back, I had asked "Way to convert an answer to a comment?", and got answer that Diamond moderators are given this feature.

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837050/con-getinputstream-throw-exception-in-android-project-how-to-fix) where the accepted answer was in a comment which the person who asked acknowledged correctly.

I think it would be a good idea to have an option for moderators to convert a comment into an answer based on a flag. Then it is left to the person who asked the question to award reputation and or accepted answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So far, comment authors have handled it just fine. I've seen more than once OP asking commenter to post his information as an answer, so it could be accepted. It was always done.

Why do we need moderators for that?

Talking about this particular case, **Jems** most likely haven't seen the reply. I'll post a link to [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) for **kimo**.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As I did not see such cases, I raised this question. You are right, if this can be resolved without moderator, there is no feature change required. As for this particular case, I was not involved anywhere. Now, I have added a comment for Jems to add his comment as an answer.

Comment: @TheCottonSilk Sorry, I was careless reading your post :/

Comment: We need moderators for that because lots of moderators just delete answers or flag them that they think should be comments.