# Wrong answer, but right comment

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Marking comment as an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77900/marking-comment-as-an-answer)

Sometimes an answer is given that is either wrong or shows a misunderstanding of the question, but in the ensuing comments the right answer is given.  How do I, as the person who posted the question, indicate this and credit the commenter who provided the solution?

Checking the checkmark seems wrong in this case.

(Edit: once I posted this I got a list of "related" topics, one of which asks essentially the same question: [Marking comment as an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77900/marking-comment-as-an-answer))

Comment: Just leave a comment asking them to make it an answer so you can accept it. I'm sorry, I couldn't help myself.

Comment: Correct!  Accepted.  :)

Comment: @Tim But you did help! (read again)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options:

- Leave a comment reply and tell the person that their advice worked, you'd love it if they made their comment an answer that you could accept.
- If they don't .. you can write their comment as an answer (giving them credit) and accept it.

Most people will be eager to know they helped, get a few reputation points and another accepted answer under their belt. They may also put more work (beyond what is expected in a comment) into their post.

If they don't .. there's [nothing wrong with answering your own question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), provided that you credit the person who helped you. You can do that by quoting the comment and providing a link to their user page.