# What should I do when I want to accept a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

In [How can I install Linux Mint in a VMware Fusion VM? It fails to boot](https://superuser.com/questions/544773/how-can-i-install-linux-mint-in-a-vmware-fusion-vm-it-fails-to-boot), someone solved my problem in a comment. Should I ask the poster to restate his comment in an answer so I can accept it, or is there a better way to deal with a problem solved based only on comments?

Comment: Closely Related: [Wrong answer but right comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97332/wrong-answer-but-right-comment), and ultimately [Marking comment as an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77900/marking-comment-as-an-answer)

Answer (score 14):

Yes, ask the commenter to make an answer from his comment so that you can upvote and accept it.  If he doesn't do that in a reasonable period of time, then make the answer yourself, and self-accept it.

Comment: This is exactly what you should do. It's generally nice to quote the comment and give credit by linking to the author's user page when you do this. Don't link to the comment itself, as comments are churned and deleted on a very frequent basis. Whenever possible, put a little more detail (beyond what is expected in a comment) into your self-answer, but that's by no means a requirement.

Comment: @TimPost, I agree, attribution is a good thing.