# Question answered in comments indicator

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, unanswered-questions

In the unanswered section of many sites there are a lot of questions that have 0 answers but when you go and look at them someone has suggested an answer in the comments, this creates unnecessary questions to be put in the unanswered section, thus clogging it up. To fix this would it be possible to put a button next to each comment(A little check mark or something along those lines)that would indicate if that comment solved the askers problem. If this is the case one of two things could happen.

1:
    The correctly chosen comment could be converted into an answer and then either be automatically chosen as the right answer or just put up as a answer.

2:
    The question still technically will have 0 answers but it will be moved out of the unanswered category, allowing for actual unanswered questions to be in there.

Comment: Just add an answer yourself?

Comment: @Bart The whole point of this feature would be to make it so people don't have to add an answer, instead it just wouldn't show up as unanswered.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I saw that one, however no one(as far as I saw) suggested making it automatically turn into an answer.

Comment: Yet we want real answers.

Comment: @Bart This would only be used in cases were someone forgot a closing html tag or something and users felt like that would be to short of an answer.

Comment: Thats pointless. Answer the question, or close it if it doesn't deserve one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Marking comment as an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77900/marking-comment-as-an-answer), [What should I do when I want to accept a comment?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165768), and all the other dupes I list [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100729/add-a-feature-to-migrate-a-comment-into-an-answer).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We really do not want to encourage any final outcome other than questions + answers.

If nobody is stepping up to the plate to write an answer but the answer has clearly been found in the comments, by all means snipe the rep -- take the collective knowledge that's been patched together and actually patch it together into a cohesive full answer.

Comment: Ok. So it sounds like comments will not be chosen as answers because they are usually short. Rather than marking the comment as the answer take the knowledge and create a jsfiddle or something.

Comment: I agree with this. But if, for whatever reason, you feel uncomfortable taking the rep, you could always mark your answer as "community wiki". And it's not an abuse of community wiki because the answer really was reached by community collaboration.