# Add a "convert-comment-to-answer" button

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, answers, convert-to-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mark a comment as answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question)

I find that in many cases a comment I've made turns out to be the answer to the question. I suggest adding a "convert-comment-to-answer" button.

Comment: Why can't you delete or flesh out the non-answer into an answer? What rep does this even come to kick in?

Comment: What about [feature-request] to vote to convert comment to the answer?

Comment: Maybe we get 5 comments a day we can turn into answers. Anybody's comment. Anywhere, anytime.

Answer (score 7):

If it is a comment, it is too short for an answer.

You can easily click the `edit` link next to your comment, copy to an answer and *improve/flesh out* before posting, then deleting the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times, comment doesn't fit as an answer, because comments are too short.

Sometimes it would be useful, though

However, I do not think this would ever become [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), because it's too simple to just copy your comment and put it as an answer instead