# Is it possible for moderators to convert a comment into an answer?

Tags: feature-request

Looking at the [comment](https://serverfault.com/q/789155/77281) to the Q there would be a fitting answer.

It would be a nice feature for Moderators to be able to convert comments to answers (and more often vice versa).

Possible or not?

Comment: No, it's not. They can move answers to comments, but not the other way around.

Comment: Interesting. There was an up vote for that feature in the past. So why not implement it?

Comment: @Nils There are a lot of features with upvotes which never get implemented, or take years. The dev team has more ideas than time to implement them, and while the community has input, they can't insist on changes.

Comment: @Mithrandir I am requesting that feature for Mod. The linked Q asked for the questioner.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273941/can-we-allow-moderators-to-upgrade-a-comment-to-an-answer?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Mithrandir ok. close my Q as duplicate.

Comment: I think it would be yet better, if even the community could do it, with votes, as usual. Poke me, I am dreaming...

Comment: @peterh That would require a different upvote for comments. Tricky to programming. And there were reasons not to give that right to ordinary users

Comment: @Nils Why? Initally, the concept of the SE was that everything is being done by the community. There is the reputation system, there are the rules, if multiple, high-rep users are needed for an action, it can't cause too big problems (until it is not very important).

Comment: @peterh - You indicated that you wanted the community to be able to convert comments into answers by upvoting them, the reason that cannot be done is that would require a **new** system to be created, just for comments.  If the comment is so good, somebody should reference the comment, and simply submit an answer.