# Elevating a comment to answer

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mark a comment as answer to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question)

I've come a cross a situation a few times where some good SO citizen has provided me with an answer in his or her comment. When this happens I have asked the commentor to report as an answer so I could accept it but this normally doesn't happen. That puts me in a situation where I would like to be able to accept the comment as the answer to my question. Could this feature be implemented?

Comment: You can always repost the comment as an answer yourself and accept that. (Well, if you have 15 reputation.)

Comment: Yes, I know, but as the answer has already been given I feel I would rob the contributor from his/her well deserved reputation in doing that.

Comment: Don't feel bad. If you've asked and there is no response then you've done all you could do. Just post it as an answer. You can always correct the situation should the original answerer respond in the end.

Comment: This has [been proposed before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question) and was declined. I sometimes post very terse answers as comments simply because I want to help someone, but don't have time / inclination to write a lengthy formal answer to be vetted through the voting process.

Comment: A comment rarely makes a good answer, "elevating" it would mean asking for it to be flagged as "not an answer". If the person doesn't do the effort of turning the comment into a proper answer then that's just the way it is.