# Answered but not registered as answered

Tags: discussion, comments, unanswered-questions

Sometimes I see questions like: [Syntax error at or near "EXCEPTION"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727319/syntax-error-at-or-near-exception)

The answer was given in a comment and user who asked said that it solved his problem. The thing is that this question will continue to be seen in "unanswered questions".

This is not a case where answers were given and the user who asked was gone. He gave a comment saying that the answer is good. Shouldn't there be a way to mark this questions as answered even though there was no "Official" answer.

Comment: Have you seen this post: [Mark a comment as answer to a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question)

Comment: @HackerKarma not entirely the same. OP asks if the question should be marked answered, not the comment as an answer. I do agree it is strongly related. Also, it is answered from the question asker's point of view, not from a bystander as in this case.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I reread three times OP's question, your answer and the link I posted above. Like you said "I do agree it is strongly related" My head is spinning... +1 for BOTH of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, questions answered through a comment aren't very hard to solve/answer and are either duplicates of previous questions or (as I see it in this case) a typographical issue. Sometimes a simple Google search would have done the trick sufficiently. In this case I don't think it is particularly useful to keep the question.

In general, if a question was answered through a comment and you think the question and answer were very useful, you could opt to answer the question through a community wiki answer, with proper attribution to the user which placed the comment. Just copy pasting the comment doesn't seem they useful, consider upgrading the comment to an answer explaining a little more.

If you can, expand the answer even more so it becomes a very useful answer. In that case, you could even consider it your own answer which wouldn't require it to become a community wiki.

Comment: In that case there isn't much expending to do. I'm wondring what is the policy.. is it just going to be left as is?

Comment: @user2641077 I voted to close as a simple typographical issue.

Comment: So in the future the suggestion is to vote closing?

Comment: In this case you could indeed vote to close.